# Вычисления с процентами для типа int

Tags: java

Число нужно увеличить на 10%, в методе параметр `i` должен быть `int`. Делал через `double` — работает, но в онлайн курсе тестирование не проходит.

```
public class Solution {
    public static int addTenPercent(int i) {
        return i = i + i * 10 / 100;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(addTenPercent(9));
    }
}
```

Comment: Кавычки в коде нету, я ее случайно здесь поставил

Comment: а какой ожидается результат 10% от 9 в целочисленном эквиваленте? 0 или 1? А возвращаемое значение должно быть `int` или всё же `double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
public class Solution {
    public static int addTenPercent(int i) {
        return i*1.1;
    }
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если результат должен быть int: `return (int) (i + i * (10.0f / 100.0f));`
Для точных вычислений лучше использовать [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).